# Retract and homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I have this problem in Hatcher's book :

> Show that if $A$ is a retract of $X$ then the map $H_{n}(A)\rightarrow H_{n}(X)$ induced by the inclusion $A\subset X$ is injective.

I think I have problems with homology sequences, because (for me) this map is always injective.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. For example, for $A= \mathbb S^1 \subset \mathbb R = X$, the induced map on homology is not injective. (Of course $A$ is not a retract of $X$ in this case).

Comment: Remember, $r\colon X\to A$ is a retraction if and only if $r\circ i=\mbox{Id}_A$ where $i\colon A\to X$ is inclusion. In particular, $r_*\circ i_*=\mbox{Id}_{H_n(A)}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the homology exact sequence, you merely need functoriality of homology: $H(r\circ j)=H(r)\circ H(j)$ and $H(id)=id_H$. The map $H(A)\rightarrow H(X)$ is not always injective, but the map on the chain level $S(A)\rightarrow S(X)$ is always injective (and is often viewed as an inclusion). Let me guess why you think that the map $H(A)\rightarrow H(X)$ is always injective. Perhaps you think that since the inclusion $A\rightarrow X$ is always injective, it always has a left inverse $X\rightarrow A$, and so the argument with the functoriality always applies. Wait, this is **WRONG**: the whole point is that in the case of a retract you have a *continuous* left inverse (and only continuous maps induce maps in homology, as the functor $H$ is defined on $\mathbf{Top}$).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\ker i_*\neq 0$. let $a\in\ker (i_*)\setminus \{0\}$. We have $0=\ker\mbox{Id}_{H_n(A)}=\ker(r_*\circ i_*)$. But note that $$(r_*\circ i_*)(a)=r_*(0)=0$$ so $a\in\ker\mbox{Id}_{H_n(A)}$. This is a contradiction by the non-triviality of $a$ so $\ker i_*=0$ hence $i_*$ is an injection. You can similarly show that $r_*$ is a surjection and you should try to show this yourself.

Comment: Why by contradiction ?...

Comment: I suppose the question is, why not? We could have just as easily proved it by saying: Let $x\in \ker i_*$. Then $i_*(x)=0$ so $(r_*\circ i_*)(x)=r_*(i_*(x))=0$ and so $x\in\ker(r_*\circ i_*)$. It follows that $\ker i_*$ is a subgroup of $\ker(r_*\circ i_*)=\mbox{Id}_{H_n(A)}=0$ hence $\ker i_*=0$.

Comment: I agree, this is quite artifical. One should use a proof by contradiction only when there is no other way. Apart from that, @Fundamentalistic is supposed to know that a function having a left inverse is always injective

Comment: @Laters I don't agree that proofs by contradiction should be avoided. It's often the way I tackle problems. I ask what would go wrong if the thing I'm trying to prove isn't true and write down a chain of implications. If ones feels awkward seeing a proof by contradiction then one probably shouldn't be doing mathematics.

Comment: @DanielRust: I never said that proofs by contradiction should be avoided in general, but they should be avoided when the result is a) obvious, and b) the direct proof is shorter (both a) and b) are fulfilled here). This proof is more like a direct proof in disguise...

Comment: @Lee I appreciate the desire for 'simple' proofs but I don't see why contradiction has to be reserved for deep results or avoided except in the direst of circumstances. It happened to be the way that I thought about it as I was typing it so I didn't see any need to simplify a proof which amounts to a couple of lines. If I had need for a more polished exposition, I might take Gowers' advice, but I feel sometimes it's better if the way you present your proof actually reflects the way you reached the conclusion.

Comment: Perhaps on a Thursday I would have thought about it in a different way and would have written the direct proof.