# Homology groups of retracts of algebraic topological spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Sup, recently I had an extremely vivid dream about algebraic topology. In it, I computed the homology group of the Klien Bottle $K$ to be

$$H_1(K) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$$

Now, my dream concluded with the definition of a *retract*:

Suppose that the inclusion map $$\iota : A \longrightarrow X$$ is left invertible, then we say that $A$ is a retract of $X$.

For when I go to bed tonight and dream about more algebraic topology (like I always do) I was wondering if there is a retract $A$ of the Klein bottle with $H_1(A) \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$.

Do retracts have to have homology groups that are subgroups of the homology groups of the original topological space (which has has homology groups)?

My attempts at the question: many attempts were made but i kept waking up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retract and homology](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091082/retract-and-homology)

Comment: I don't agree. There is one more question which Christoph hasn't addressed and which didn't appear in the link you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an inclusion $i\colon A \hookrightarrow X$ with retraction $r\colon X\to A$, so $r\circ i = \operatorname{id}_A$. Then also in homology $r_* \circ i_* = \operatorname{id}_{H_*(A)}$. We conclude that $i_*$ gives injections $H_*(A) \hookrightarrow H_*(X)$, so in fact $H_1(A)$ will be isomorphic to a subgroup of $H_1(X)$, namely $i_*(H_1(A)) \subseteq H_1(X)$.

Comment: Now the remaining question is whether there exists a retract $A$ such that $H_1(A)\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$. My guess is no.

Comment: This is interesting. How would one go about proving  this?

Comment: Here's my rough reasoning. $A$ is either 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional. In the former case, $A$ is a union of circles and intervals, whose first homology can never be $\mathbb{Z}_2$. In the latter case, assuming further that $A$ is a closed surface, then using classification of surfaces we have that $A$ must be $\mathbb{RP}^2$, but then I don't think $\mathbb{RP}^2$ can be embedded into Klein bottle as a retract.

Comment: @AlexFok How are you sure that $A$ is a manifold?

Comment: @BalarkaSen: As long as you have a $C^1$ retract, the image is always a manifold. (Great challenge to prove this.) But it's not so with $C^0$.